WPF app with Instagram and Facebook login - is this possible?
I have big app for managing/organizing photos. One of functionality is publishing (with rescaling, adding signature etc.) with descriptions (from program database). I added e.g. publishing to Skyscrapercity.
Now I want to add publishing to:
*) Instagram, to my own account
*) Facebook:
**) post to my own accoount,
**) creating albums in my own account,
**) post to group I belong (multi pic to one post, with metadata/description to each pic)
I think facebook login as "device login" would be best, because it doesn't require adding http server functionality to my app. But it seems that I should first get access code. When I try to do it, I got message that my app is not allowed to use login (but it has 'device login' enabled).
I suspect that I have to convert my private account to business account, than allow my app to be verified by Facebook - but app has ~15 thousands lines of code, so it would take months :)
Can anyone give me some hints / guide me through adding FB posting functionality to desktop WPF app?
    var sUri = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login?access_token={FB_APP_ID}|{FB_CLNT_TOKEN}&scope=public_profile"

    var sPage = await Vblib.HttpPageAsync(sUri)
    // got: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

Where HttpPageAsync is library function, in short (stripping down error handling etc.)
    var oResp = await moHttp.GetAsync(oUri)
    var sPage = await oResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

